# How to use block attributes in view.js in WP?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I tried the new npm package `@wordpress/create-block` to generate custom blocks in WordPress.

The file `view.js` was created automatically in my blocks folder. In the `view.js` i can write JavaScript Code for my custom block.

Now i want to use the block attributes in `view.js` but i cannot find in wp docs how to pass the information into my view.js file?

I placed the attributes in `block.json`.

```
"attributes": {
    "content": {
        "type": "string",
        "source": "html",
        "selector": "h2",
    },
    "question": {
        "type": "string",
        "source": "html",
        "selector": "div",
    },
    "autoplay": {
        "type": "boolean",
    },
    "loop": {
        "type": "boolean",
    },
},
```

How can i use for e.g. the `attributes.autoplay` or `attributes.loop` in view.js?

Comment: I am searching with you for the answer and the best solution I have found at the moment is to pass them as a data-attribute or within a script tag.